# The following code's list function not working

Tags: c, function, file, record

The following code is an employee management system. There are four functions: insert, list, edit and exit. This issue is present at the void list function, line 148 a. It's not displaying the list of employees. It seems mostly correct to me. I ask if someone can please kindly assist?

This is the struct:

```
struct employee
{
        char name[50];
        char sex[7];
        char adrs[50];
        char dsgn[25];
        int age,empID;
        float slry;
};

List function:

void list ()
{
     printf("-------------------------------");
     printf("\nEmployee Details: \n---------------------------------\n");
     rewind(fptr);///moves file to start of the file
     while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr)==1)///read the file and fetch the record one record per fetch
     {
         printf("\n\n%s \t\t%6s \t%s \t%s \t%d \t%.2f \t%d",e.name, e.sex, e.adrs, e.dsgn, e.age, 
e.slry, e.empID);
     }
     getch();
```

Entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "struct.h"

void insert();
void list();
void edit();
void del();
void exit();
int tolower();

FILE * fptr, *ftemp;
struct employee e;
long int recsize;
char empname[50];

int main()
{
    int choice;
    fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "r+");


    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't find file! Attempting to create file... \n");

        fptr = fopen("ems.txt","w+");
        if(fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Can't create file. Exiting...");
         exit(1);
        }
    }

    //Explain the reason for this?
    //recsize = (long int) sizeof(e);//


    while(1)
    {
        printf("*******************************\n");
        printf("\nEmployee management system");
        printf("\n1. Insert employee information");
        printf("\n2. List all employee information");
        printf("\n3. Edit employee information");
        printf("\n4. Delete employee information");
        printf("\n5. Exit");
        printf("\n\n*****************************\n");
        printf("\n\n Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                puts("Insert was chosen");
                insert();

                break;
            case 2:
                puts("List was chosen");
                list();
                break;
            case 3:
                puts("Edit was chosen");
                edit();
                break;
            case 4:
                puts("Delete was chosen");
                del();
                break;
            case 5:
                puts("Exit was chosen");
                exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                puts("Choice is incorrect!!");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void insert()
{
    char next;

    do
    {
        printf("********************************************************** \n");
        printf("\nEnter the name of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.name, sizeof(e.name), stdin);
        printf("\nEnter the sex of the employee (M/m or F/f): ");
        scanf("%6s",e.sex);

        switch(*e.sex)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                printf("\nMale.\n");
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                printf("\nFemale.\n  ");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unspecified Sex.");
        }

        printf("\nEnter the address of the employee: ");

        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // ADD THIS TO AVOID SKIP

        fgets(e.adrs, sizeof(e.adrs), stdin); // this
        printf("\nEnter designation of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.dsgn, sizeof(e.dsgn), stdin); // this

        printf("\nEnter age of the employee: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.age);
        printf("\nEnter basic salary of the employee: ");
        scanf("%f", &e.slry);
        printf("\nEnter the employee's ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.empID);
        fputs(e.name, fptr);
        fputs(e.sex, fptr);
        fputs(e.adrs, fptr);
        fputs(e.dsgn, fptr);
        fprintf(fptr, "%d \n%f \n%d \n", e.age, e.slry, e.empID);
       // fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fptr);
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
        //fflush(stdin);//
        printf("\nDo you want to input more? (y/n): ");
        next = getche();
        printf("\n");
    }
    while( tolower(next) != 'n' );

    fclose(fptr);
}

void list ()
{
     printf("-------------------------------");
     printf("\nEmployee Details: \n---------------------------------\n");
     rewind(fptr);///moves file to start of the file
     while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr)==1)///read the file and fetch the record one record per fetch
     {
         printf("\n\n%s \t\t%6s \t%s \t%s \t%d \t%.2f \t%d",e.name, e.sex, e.adrs, e.dsgn, e.age, e.slry, e.empID);
     }
     getch();

     /*printf("Name        : %s\n",e.name);
     printf("Address     : %s\n",e.adrs);
     printf("Sex         : %c\n",e.sex);
     printf("Designation : %s\n",e.dsgn);
     printf("Age         : %d\n",e.age);
     printf("Salary      : %.2f\n",e.slry);
     printf("Employee-ID : %d\n",e.empID);*/
}

void edit ()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the employee's name to be edited: ");
        scanf("%49[^\n]", empname);
        rewind(fptr);
        while(fread(&e, recsize, 1, fptr)==1)///fetch all records from file
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) == 0) ///if entered name matches with that in file
                printf("\nEnter new name, sex, address, designation, age, salary and employee ID: ");
                scanf("%s%c%s%s%d%f%d", e.name, e.sex, e.adrs, e.dsgn, &e.age, &e.slry, &e.empID);
                fseek(fptr, -recsize, SEEK_CUR);/// move cursor 1 step back from current position
                fwrite(&e, recsize,1,fptr); ///override the record
                break;
        }

        printf("\nEdit another record(y/n)");
        next = getche();
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}

    }
    while(next != 'n');

    return ;
}

void del()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter name of employee to delete: ");
        scanf("%s",empname);
        ftemp = fopen("Temp.dat","wb"); ///create a intermediate file for temporary storage
        rewind(fptr); ///move record to starting of file
        while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr) == 1)  ///read all records from file
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0)  ///if the entered record match
            {
                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ftemp); ///move all records except the one which is to be deleted to temp file
            }
        }

        fclose(fptr);
        fclose(ftemp);
        remove("ems.txt"); ///remove original file
        rename("Temp.dat","ems.txt"); ///rename temp file to original file name
        fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "rb+");
        printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
        next = getche();


    }while( tolower(next) != 'n' );
    fclose(fptr);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I like to check scanf() return to ensure the field is actually filled.  Never trust input data!  Error checking is nice, too.  Note that fgets() leaves the linefeed in your data.  Does it print anything?  Does a dump of the data file show it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the list of employees, you should use **EOF** like this.

```
fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr)!=EOF
```

I wish it's helpful for you.

Comment: I tried that and now getting a list but it's printing infinitely. Any clue?

Comment: If you have got an runtime error, you should change code like this. fread(&e, recsize, 1, fptr) == recsize